# How to overwrite nginx default config with docker file?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-config

I have an app which is using React router, and I created a docker image for it. I am using nginx server and it works. But, refreshing a page gives me nginx 404 error. I know that I need to overwrite nginx config file to make it work, but don't know why it doesn't work.

I tried to add some kind of redirect to `nginx.conf` just to see if it overrides `default.conf` but it doesn't work. These are my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80 default;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 301 https://www.google.com;
 }
```

EDIT:

And how to check what config file is running?

Comment: what url are u using to access the container?

Comment: localhost - i am ruining container with docker run -p 80:80 frontend

Answer (score 6):

I believe you should use

```
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

If you want to organise things in `conf.d/`, add `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` before adding things in `conf.d/`

Complete config file:

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
      listen       80 default;
      server_name  localhost;
      return 301 https://www.google.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try this config file? maybe nginx failed to launch

Comment: thanks for helping, but still doesnt resolve it... dont think it failed to lunch cause on refresh i get 404 error from nginx

Comment: yea my mistake when i was copying the code, i edited now, but that is not the problem, my ngix conf still doesnt overide default one

Comment: I'm having the same dockerfile as yours, mine works. Check to make sure it's not another nginx that runs, rebuild image and run it.

Comment: i did all of that, delete all unsed images (had two diffrent nginx), then rebuild it and run it, now have only one that is running, still doesnt work

Comment: ok i cant believe what i was doing, i was starting wrong docker image, everything works fine